# Can excel read and write to a phpmyadmin database?

Tags: php, excel, vba

I am developing an application in excel in which data can be updated remotely ie, data is read from an online database and loaded into excel upon start up. I know this can be done by reading from html tables on a website however, was wondering if it could be done through phpmyadmin directly.

Comment: There is no such thing as a phpmyadmin database..... there is a MySQL database, phpmyadmin is a client utility for accessing a MySQL database

Comment: It may be possible to connect from Excel to MySQL using ODBC - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can (surprisingly).

Though I strongly recommend exposing your MySQL database as an ODBC data source instead.

In Excel, create a new spreadsheet and go to the Data tab, and under "External Data" choose "From web query", then follow the instructions and enter thr address of your phpMyAdmin installation, login, get to the data, then select the table. Excel will remember your login details and cookies for future data refreshes, though it can be a bit wonky as the feature hasn't really been updated in over a decade (source: I asked some members of the Excel dev team a few weeks ago myself)

Comment: I went onto phpmyadmin and into browse to locate the data but was unable to select the data to import into excel, should I be in a different tab?

Comment: How were you "unable to select the data", was the yellow overlay icon not visible?

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin is just a GUI for PHP functions that connect to a MySQL database. You would have to communicate directly with the database or via a PHP script that does so for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.  Its just simple.

Take an example that you have a table with following fields.

1) ID 2) Name 3) Email

Now create a csv with 3 columns in it with the data, for eg

1,Rushit,Rushitdawda@gmail.com
2,Test,test@gmail.com

Now go to phpmyadmin and create a table and then go to import & upload the sheet and you are done..